# Is there a R function that can assign the same number to same observations?

Tags: r, indexing

I am new in R coding. I was wondering if someone can please help me.

I have a data of this form :

```
   worker   firm's id
   JDNC       A
   NXZD       A
   KDHD       A
   BCSI       A
   QGUQ       B
   BCIS       C
   QNXJ       A
   JQXQ       V
   JQHX       X
```

but actually I have 300 different id's ans 46900 workers. So I want something like this:

```
   worker   firm's id   index
   JDNC       A          1
   NXZD       A          1
   KDHD       A          1
   BCSI       A          1
   QGUQ       B          2
   BCIS       C          3
   LOPH       C          3
   QNXJ       A          1
   JQXQ       V          4
   JQHX       X          5
   JSDH       V          4
   HHHH       V          4
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> firm$index <- as.numeric(as.factor(firm$`firm id`))
> firm
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  worker `firm id` index
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 JDNC   A             1
2 NXZD   A             1
3 KDHD   A             1
4 BCSI   A             1
5 QGUQ   B             2
6 BCIS   C             3
7 QNXJ   A             1
8 JQXQ   V             4
9 JQHX   X             5
>
```

data:

```
> dput(firm)
structure(list(worker = c("JDNC", "NXZD", "KDHD", "BCSI", "QGUQ", 
"BCIS", "QNXJ", "JQXQ", "JQHX"), `firm id` = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "V", "X")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: fyi `match(x, unique(x))` is more efficient.

Comment: @Karthik Yes it works perfectly thank you for your help!